# Expansion issue in tasks package

Tags: expansion, tasks

I'm trying to switch from `enumitem` lists to `tasks` lists, but the following, which works in an ordinary `enumerate` environment, generates a "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" error in the `tasks` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newcommand{\itemexpansion}{\item test \item test \item test \item test}
\newcommand{\taskexpansion}{\task test \task test \task test \task test}

\begin{document}
% OK
\begin{enumerate}
    \itemexpansion
\end{enumerate}
% Error
\begin{tasks}
    \taskexpansion
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

I can tell that there's an expansion problem here, but that's about as far as my comprehension extends. It doesn't seem to match the situations warned about in the manual. Is there a workaround that will allow me to dump the results of a macro (the contents of which are gathered elsewhere) into a `tasks` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tasks` needs to explicitly see `\task`.

You can add a “command” form of `tasks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dotasks}{O{}d()m}
 {
  \hagen_tasks:Vnn { #3 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_tasks:nnn
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #3 }
   {
    \begin{tasks}[#2]#1\end{tasks}
   }
   {
    \begin{tasks}[#2](#3)#1\end{tasks}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hagen_tasks:nnn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\itemexpansion}{\item test \item test \item test \item test}
\newcommand{\taskexpansion}{\task test \task test \task test \task test}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \itemexpansion
\end{enumerate}

\dotasks{\taskexpansion}

\dotasks(2){\taskexpansion}

\dotasks[counter-format=(tsk[r]),label-width=4ex](2){\taskexpansion}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I create a new `Tasks` environment that calls upon `tasks`, while expanding the first argument (in this case, `\taskexpansion`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,environ}
\newcommand{\itemexpansion}{\item test \item test \item test \item test}
\newcommand{\taskexpansion}{\task test \task test \task test \task test}
\NewEnviron{Tasks}{%
  \def\tmp{\begin{tasks}}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp\BODY%
  \end{tasks}%
}
\begin{document}
% OK
\begin{enumerate}
    \itemexpansion
\end{enumerate}
% No longer Error
\begin{Tasks}
    \taskexpansion
\end{Tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]